# AWS S3 Elastic Beanstalk Docker - /dev/fus: Operation not permitted

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, s3fs

I am new to AWS EB and S3. I want to deploy a Docker containter with beanstalk and an s3 mount in it. The problem is, that I get the message that /dev/fuse is not permitted.

(using [s3fs](https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse))

After a long night and more than 120 deploys with different setups I need your help.

I did added a .ebextension folder with a config file. I tested to replace the eb docker run command with docker run --previleged and some other...

I did tested the configs from this one:  [How to install Ghost](https://www.ghostforbeginners.com/how-to-install-ghost-on-aws-elastic-beanstalk/)

It work's more or less, but it created a s3 mount on the host machine - not in the docker and the docker installation failed, because of this message:

> Activity execution failed, because: rm: cannot remove ‘/var/app/current/content’: Device or resource busy (ElasticBeanstalk::ExternalInvocationError)
>   caused by: rm: cannot remove ‘/var/app/current/content’: Device or resource busy (Executor::NonZeroExitStatus)

I want to run a wordpress installation in the docker instance and I need the s3 for the uploads folder.

Is there any solution to fix this?

Thanks and Cheers

Comment: hello devHead, I am having the same issue, Did you find a solution?